# IFrame Shortcode plugin - issue

Tags: shortcode, iframe

`[iframe src="https://www.quora.com/" data-no-lazy="1"]`

Hey guys I'm trying to add external webpage to wordpress. I'm using "Flyn San" plugin for that but its not working properly. I have attached the iframe above also sharing you the link of my website.

This is my webpage link : https://netbramhadev.wpengine.com
Extra page links : https://netbramhadev.wpengine.com/dummy/

Thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the browser's development tools you'll see this error:

> Refused to display 'https://www.quora.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

This means that Quora does not allow itself to be used in iframes. If you're just testing, then try another URL. If you actually want to embed Quora, then I'm afraid that doesn't appear to be possible.

Comment: No not showing this kind of error. I got error like "failed to load plugin url" from wordpress

Comment: Is this because of any other plugin?